# Why do SSMS scripts include the server name?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I generate a script in SSMS it creates a fully qualified name.

`[Server].[schema].[table]`

In my experience, having the server name in the script gets in the way of the deployment process.  E.G. Dev > Test > Prod.  The server name is also not required to successfully execute the script.  So I tend to remove the name anytime I generate scripts.

I realize there's no silver bullet and MS tends to make such decisions carefully.  So what is the thinking behind this?  Is including the server name a best practice for some reason?  If so, what is the best practice for deploying scripts across environments?

Comment: If you want to automatically generate scripts for deployment, I wouldn't use SSMS scripts: try the Red Gate tools for this. I've always thought that the SSMS scripts are just a starting point: they try to be all inclusive code, with as many fields and qualifications as reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's not the standard behavior

you may have change something to scriot the server name.

Try setting the "Schema qualify object names" general setting to false.

In theory it should remove the [schema] part. Maybe it will remove the server name as well

Comment: I've performed various installations of SQL including various versions of SQL.  As I recall, each installation scripted with the server name by default.

Comment: hum...mine doesn't and I'm on SSMS 2008 querying a 2008 DB on a Developer Edition